# PHP---if(!session_is_registered deprecated?

Tags: php

This if statement has been deprecated

```
if(!session_is_registered('firstname')){ 
header("location: index.php"); // << makes the script send them to any page we set
} else {
print "<h2>Could not log you out, sorry the system encountered an error.</h2>";
exit();
}
```

I replaced it with

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['firstname'] ) ){
header("location: index.php"); // << makes the script send them to any page we set
} else {
print "<h2>Could not log you out, sorry the system encountered an error.</h2>";
exit();
```

the initial code is attached to my logout.php script. When i then go to the link logout.php, this is displayed "Could not log you out, sorry the system encountered an error."

Is that the right solution since i had no problem with the code

Comment: If it's possible for `$_SESSION['firstname']` to be null but set, try `array_key_exists('firstname', $_SESSION)`  Also, it appears in the first example that you redirect if the variable doesn't exist, in the second, you redirect if it does exist.  Is that your intended action?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first snippet, I think you are failing in logic.

Try:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['firstname']) ){
    header("location: index.php"); // << makes the script send them to any page we set
} else {
    exit('<h2>Could not log you out, sorry the system encountered an error.</h2>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have session_start(); on your page?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.